# Liquibase: 'dropForeignKeyConstrant' is not a valid element of a ChangeSet

Tags: database, postgresql, maven, groovy, liquibase

Get this error:

`Error setting up or running Liquibase: ChangeSet '02': 'dropForeignKeyConstrant' is not a valid element of a ChangeSet`

pom.xml plugin(in .prop only credentials for db)

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
    <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.10.2</version>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
        <artifactId>liquibase-groovy-dsl</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.2</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.15</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
      <propertyFile>src/main/resources/liquibase.properties</propertyFile>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

ChangeSet(.groovy)

```
 rollback {
        
        dropUniqueConstraint(schemaName: schema_name, tableName: 'bucket', constraintName: 'u_bucket_name')
        dropUniqueConstraint(schemaName: schema_name, tableName: 'version', constraintName: 'u_bucket_key')

        dropForeignKeyConstrant(baseTableSchemaName: schema_name, baseTableName: 'file', constraintName: 'file_type_fk')
        dropForeignKeyConstrant(baseTableSchemaName: schema_name, baseTableName: 'license', constraintName: 'file_fk')
```

As you can see `dropUniqueConstraint` worked, but dropForeignKeyConstrant didn't

Why i got this error and how to fix this?

Comment: Hi, is `dropForeignKeyConstrant` instead of `dropForeignKeyConstraint` a typo in the question or in your code?

Comment: @andi yeeeeah, it is, thanks soo much

Answer (score 0):

`DropForeignKeyConstrant` was written instead of `dropForeignKeyConstraint` (missing `i`). Thanks for your attention, @andi